# Merging Xarray Files into a new Dimension

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to merge to xarray data sets that have the same structure:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'frac' (lat: 53, lon: 178)>
dask.array<shape=(53, 178), dtype=float64, chunksize=(50, 50)>
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -23.0 -22.75 -22.5 -22.25 -22.0 -21.75 -21.5 ...
  * lon      (lon) float64 112.0 112.2 112.5 112.8 113.0 113.2 113.5 113.8 ...
```

I would like these to be merged into a new dimension called 'month' so that it looks like this:

```
Dimensions:    (lat: 53, lon: 178, month: 2)
Coordinates:
  * lon        (lon) float64 112.0 112.2 112.5 112.8 113.0 113.2 113.5 113.8 ...
  * lat        (lat) float64 -23.0 -22.75 -22.5 -22.25 -22.0 -21.75 -21.5 ...
  * month      (month) int64 10 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/combining.html) how to combine DataArrays:

```
da_concat = xr.concat([da0, da1], pd.Index([10, 11], name='month'))
```

Comment: Thank you :) All the different types of merges baffle me.